# Collapse rows in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c("a" , "b", "b", "c"),
                 id2 = c(NA,"a","a",NA),
                 id3 = c("a", "a", "a", "e"),
                 n1 = c(2,2,2,3),
                 n2 = c(2,1,1,1),
                 n3 = c(0,1,1,3),
                 n4 = c(0,1,1,2))
```

I want to collapse the `2nd` and `3rd` rows into one. Afterwards, I will do `aggregate` by column `id3` sharing same character (i.e. `a`).

My real dataframe is long contaning many different latin names, `filter` by name i.e. `a` doesn´t make sense this case. I am thinking to collapse rows with the condition `id3` == `id2`, but I could not do it. Any sugesstions for me?

My desired out put like this

```
id1 id2 id3 n1 n2 n3 n4
a   NA  a   2  2  0  0
b   a   a   2  1  1  1
c   NA  e   3  1  3  2

#Afterthat, it should be
id1 id3 n1 n2 n3 n4
a    a   4  3  1  1
c    e   3  1  3  2
```

(I just updated the dataframe, sorry for my mistake)

Comment: what is your desired "collapse" operation?

Comment: Please show us your desired output.

Comment: oh sorry thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the `distinct` rows to generate the first expected

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  distinct
  id1  id2 id3 n1 n2 n3 n4
1   a <NA>   a  2  2  0  0
2   b    a   a  2  1  1  1
3   c <NA>   e  3  1  3  2
```

---

The final output we can get from the above, i.e. after the `distinct` step, do a group by `coalesce`d 'id2', 'id1' along with 'id3' and then get the `sum` of `numeric` columns

```
df %>%
    distinct %>%
    group_by(id1 = coalesce(id2, id1), id3) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  id1   id3      n1    n2    n3    n4
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     a         4     3     1     1
2 c     e         3     1     3     2
```

Comment: I just updated my dataframe, sorry for that

Comment: @đứcanhlê i updated teh post. please check if that helps

Comment: thank you for that, how does the function `coalesce` work in this case? since i would like to learn more

Comment: @đứcanhlê It dpends on the order of input, i.e. here i used id2, id1, i.e for every row, if there is a non-Na in id2, it selects that value, if it is NA for id2, it selects the id1 value and if bothe are NA, it will be NA

Comment: thank you :D got it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different way using `slice` after `group_by` instead of `distinct`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id1, id3) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1L) %>% 
  mutate(id1 = coalesce(id2,id1)) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
```

output:

```
  id1   id3      n1    n2    n3    n4
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     a         4     3     1     1
2 c     e         3     1     3     2
```