# collapsing rows of a subset of a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce

I have the following problem:

I have three tibbles (in reality, a huge dataset), which for simplicity here are identical but in reality they are not. Maybe they might have the same Geography for some entries, but let's suppose that only the columns match, the rows are completely different:

```
T_tib1 <- tibble(
  Geography = c("World", "World", "World", "World", "World","World", "World",
                "World"),
  Category  = c("Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care",
                "Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care",
                "Laundry Care"),
  Data_Type = c("Retail Volume", "Retail Volume", "Retail Volume", 
                "Retail Volume", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)",
                "Retail Volume (Tonnes)", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)"),
  Brand = c(1:4, 1:4),
  Share_2012 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA, 12, 15, 25, 32),
  Share_2013 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA, 13, 16, 28, 33),
  Share_2014 = c(11, 19, 22, 36, NA,NA,NA,NA),
  Share_2015 = c(7, 18, 21, 38, NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

T_tib2 <- tibble(
  Geography = c("World", "World", "World", "World", "World","World", "World",
                "World"),
  Category  = c("Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care",
                "Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care",
                "Laundry Care"),
  Data_Type = c("Retail Volume", "Retail Volume", "Retail Volume", 
                "Retail Volume", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)",
                "Retail Volume (Tonnes)", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)"),
  Brand = c(1:4, 1:4),
  Share_2012 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA, 12, 15, 25, 32),
  Share_2013 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA, 13, 16, 28, 33),
  Share_2014 = c(11, 19, 22, 36, NA,NA,NA,NA),
  Share_2015 = c(7, 18, 21, 38, NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

T_tib3 <- tibble(
  Geography = c("World", "World", "World", "World", "World","World", "World",
                "World"),
  Category  = c("Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care",
                "Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care",
                "Laundry Care"),
  Data_Type = c("Retail Volume", "Retail Volume", "Retail Volume", 
                "Retail Volume", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)",
                "Retail Volume (Tonnes)", "Retail Volume (Tonnes)"),
  Brand = c(1:4, 1:4),
  Share_2012 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA, 12, 15, 25, 32),
  Share_2013 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA, 13, 16, 28, 33),
  Share_2014 = c(11, 19, 22, 36, NA,NA,NA,NA),
  Share_2015 = c(7, 18, 21, 38, NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

TIBS <- bind_rows(T_tib1, T_tib2, T_tib3)
```

Hence, `TIBS` is the dataset. I need to transform `TIBS` by transforming only `T_tib1` as the `Bobby` tibble below:

```
Bobby <- tibble(
    Geography = c("World", "World", "World", "World"),
    Category  = c("Laundry Care","Laundry Care","Laundry Care",
                  "Laundry Care"),
    Data_Type = c("Retail Volume (Tonnes or Litres)", "Retail Volume (Tonnes or Litres)",
                  "Retail Volume (Tonnes or Litres)", "Retail Volume (Tonnes or Litres)"),
    Brand = c(1:4),
    Share_2012 = c(12, 15, 25, 32),
    Share_2013 = c(13, 16, 28, 33),
    Share_2014 = c(11, 19, 22, 36),
    Share_2015 = c(7, 18, 21, 38)
  )
```

I do not understand how to this, for two reasons:

1. I tried with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69351165/collapse-rows-in-r), but here they `coalesce` immediately and this is not what I want, I need to "move above the rows" and change the character in Data_Type only for that specific rows...
2. How can I instruct R to change only a portion of the dataset? If I `filter` or `select` I create a new tibble...

Comment: It's not clear to me: you have one "huge dataset" named `TIBS`, but for the example you define _three_ frames that are identical, without clearly identifying if or how they are joined, or how we are supposed to differentiate the data in each from the others.

Comment: They are not joined, they have the same columns, that's it. I modified

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading too much in to your description. You say you have a dataset `TIBS`, is this a single frame? I think the reduction of `T_tib1` to `Bobby` is based on partial-matching `"Retail Volume"` with `"Retail Volume (Tonnes)"` and inferring that the two are the same and summarizing on the reduced set of groups, is that correct? Where are we supposed to infer `"Litres"`? I'm still unclear why we need `T_tib2` and 3 here.

Comment: Because they contain useful information! I have a dataset, a huge tibble called `TIBS`.
One subset of this tibble, calle it `T_tib1`, has the following form, and I need it as the tibble `Bobby`, but I also need every other element of `TIBS`, so I cannot filter or select.

You are not suppose to infer `Liter`, this is the content of the final cell I would like in the end, but if you call it `Pancrazio` instead of liters it's fine.

Comment: The main point is, I do not understand how to go from `T_tib1` to `Bobby` in first place, and I do not understand how to modify my dataset by "filtering and unfiltering it". Is that clearer?

Comment: `TIBS` is a list of frames? My point of `"Litres"` is that its appearance is spontaneous, never existing in the original (`T_tib*`) data.

Comment: `TIBS` is a tibble, not a list.

Comment: Okay Matteo, I've asked several times _what is TIBS_, and you keep representing it as some combination of the three frames in your question. If `TIBS` is a single frame, then why do you add complexity by presenting three identical frames? If it is in fact just a single, simple frame, does the first 2/3 of my answer address your needs?

Comment: Sorry, yes it does... I am new, I wanted to produce a minimal reproducible example, I went beyond minimal without realizing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's solve this for one frame, then we can address `TIBS`.

A function that will help translate `"Retail Volume"` to `"Retail Volume (Tonnes)"` (you can later add `"Litres"` if it's important to you.)

```r
upgrep <- function(x) {
  x0 <- unique(x)
  y <- sapply(x0, function(z) {
    out <- grep(z, x = x0, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
    out[which.max(nchar(out))]
  })
  y[x]
}
upgrep(T_tib1$Data_Type)
#            Retail Volume            Retail Volume            Retail Volume            Retail Volume   Retail Volume (Tonnes)   Retail Volume (Tonnes)   Retail Volume (Tonnes)   Retail Volume (Tonnes) 
# "Retail Volume (Tonnes)" "Retail Volume (Tonnes)" "Retail Volume (Tonnes)" "Retail Volume (Tonnes)" "Retail Volume (Tonnes)" "Retail Volume (Tonnes)" "Retail Volume (Tonnes)" "Retail Volume (Tonnes)"
```

From here, let's apply it to just one frame:

```r
T_tib1 %>%
  mutate(Data_Type = upgrep(Data_Type)) %>%
  group_by(Category, Data_Type, Brand) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 × 8
#   Category     Data_Type              Brand Geography Share_2012 Share_2013 Share_2014 Share_2015
#   <chr>        <chr>                  <int> <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     1 World             12         13         11          7
# 2 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     2 World             15         16         19         18
# 3 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     3 World             25         28         22         21
# 4 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     4 World             32         33         36         38
```

From here, to work on a list of frames, just wrap that in `lapply`, then we can reduce again:

```r
TIBS <- list(T_tib1, T_tib1, T_tib1)
Bobby <- lapply(TIBS, function(tib) {
  tib %>%
    mutate(Data_Type = upgrep(Data_Type)) %>%
    group_by(Category, Data_Type, Brand) %>%
    summarize(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.)))) %>%
    ungroup()
})
Bobby
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 × 8
#   Category     Data_Type              Brand Geography Share_2012 Share_2013 Share_2014 Share_2015
#   <chr>        <chr>                  <int> <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     1 World             12         13         11          7
# 2 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     2 World             15         16         19         18
# 3 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     3 World             25         28         22         21
# 4 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     4 World             32         33         36         38
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 4 × 8
#   Category     Data_Type              Brand Geography Share_2012 Share_2013 Share_2014 Share_2015
#   <chr>        <chr>                  <int> <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     1 World             12         13         11          7
# 2 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     2 World             15         16         19         18
# 3 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     3 World             25         28         22         21
# 4 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     4 World             32         33         36         38
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 4 × 8
#   Category     Data_Type              Brand Geography Share_2012 Share_2013 Share_2014 Share_2015
#   <chr>        <chr>                  <int> <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     1 World             12         13         11          7
# 2 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     2 World             15         16         19         18
# 3 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     3 World             25         28         22         21
# 4 Laundry Care Retail Volume (Tonnes)     4 World             32         33         36         38
```

Comment: `TIBS` is a tibble, though, in reality.